# Unable to load app.war!/WEB-INF/classes from jar files

Tags: java, jpa

I have a spring boot app which is giving the below error on creating Persistence EntityManager factory.

> Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory

The war file is available under

> /opt/test/app/app.war

and WEB-INF/classes also present in this war file.

But classloader is failing with the below error.

Is there any permission missing?

```
oggerName="org.hibernate.orm.url" threadName="main" txnId="" HHH10000002: File or directory named by URL [file:/opt/test/app/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes] could not be found.  URL will be ignored
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/test/app/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.resolveJarFileReference(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
```

Docker file reference,

```
FROM alpine/jdk1.8:latest
RUN mkdir -p /opt/test/app
COPY app.war /opt/test/app/app.war

CMD java -jar /opt/test/app/app.war
```

Comment: How did you build the `.war` file?

Comment: The war file was built using mvn clean install and also it is being deployed as a docker image. Is there permission to be granted in the docker file?

Comment: I'm running into this same message, but I'm only seeing this as a warning, not an error: `[WARN ] 2018-07-26 07:46:40,253 org.hibernate.orm.url - HHH10000002: File or directory named by URL [...] could not be found.  URL will be ignored ...`. My application seems to continue on as expected.  Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: Did anybody find a solution or reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml, change the packaging to jar